# Faster way to create timestamp string in %.7f format

Tags: java, optimization, timestamp

This is a function I have to create timestamp string in %.7f format.  This function takes only 2-3 ms to execute. But its called from many places in my code, by even optimizing it by 1 ms I will save 1 second in one particular user action.  Any ideas?

```
public static String makeTimestamp()
{
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String result;
    Double ts = new Double((millis) / 1000.0);

    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(b);
    p.printf("%.7f", ts );
    result = b.toString();
    try
    {
        p.close();
        b.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {};
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Evaluating the three answers (at the time of evaluation) these are the times, in nanoSecs  `Original:2691355
Option 1:82347
Option 2:87703
Option 3:20754`.  As you can see option 3 (the char[] implmentation) is much faster. But I tend to go with Option 2, since I am pretty sure my software will be running in 2286 ;)

Comment: I agree with keeping it simple unless you really need it to be faster, so the shorter answer is probably best for you. Seeing as how I like a challenge though, I went ahead and fixed my version to support past the year 2286. To properly benchmark the options you need to iterate at least a few thousand times to see how it differs once JIT takes effect. I'm still showing 10 times faster with Java 6 Update 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need it, this is roughly 10 times faster than string formatting:

```
public static String makeTimestamp() {
    return formatTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), 7);
}

public static String formatTime(long millis, int fractionDigits) {
    int integerDigits = (int) Math.log10(millis / 1000.0) + 1;

    char[] chars = new char[integerDigits + fractionDigits + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = '0';
    }

    millis *= Math.pow(10, fractionDigits - 3);
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i == integerDigits) {
            chars[i] = '.';
            i--;
        }

        chars[i] = (char) (millis % 10);
        chars[i] += '0';

        millis /= 10;
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the note, now add it as a comment in the code so that it's kept when someone copies-and-pastes this into their codebase (which I'm sure will happen).

Comment: @Joachim: good point, I've moved the notes into code comments so they're kept when people copy and paste

Comment: Updated my code to support past the year 2286 and a variable number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much faster it is, but how about

```
public static String makeTimestamp()
{
    return String.format("%.7f", ((double)System.currentTimeMillis())/1000);
}
```

(and I am not sure why we bring double into the picture).

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear why you're going through a PrintStream etc. What's wrong with:

```
public static String makeTimestamp()
{
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return String.format("%.7f", millis / 1000.0);
}
```

On my netbook that takes around 0.04ms per iteration... but even your original code only takes around 0.1ms per iteration. What are you running on that takes 2-3ms at the moment? Are you running in a debugger, for example? I can't understand why it would be so slow - it's not like my netbook is a particularly fast machine.

All performance matters aside though, I'd say the main benefit of the above method over your original is simplicity. The original is very complicated for no good reason at all.

Comment: my box is running Sun JVM 1.5 on FreeBSD.  Probably different platforms/jvms do this more efficiently, I haven't tested though.

Comment: @Nishan: Have you tested *just* using `System.currentTimeMillis`? It's possible that that's the bottleneck.